# React-native (expo) ImagePicker storing unwanted copy of photographs

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Is there a way to either prevent `Expo.ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync` from storing images in the `Internal shared storage/Pictures` folder on Android or to delete them immediately after they're created? There's a copy stored in the Expo app cache folder so I don't see why this duplicate is needed.

I know I could detach my app and use something like this: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker (which does appear to give you this option), but I'd rather not if possible.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: The `react-native-image-picker` that you have linked has the same issue actually